# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error

Tags: spring, java-8, jackson

I've an response from 3rd party like below

```
[
    {
        "url": "https://abc/10",
        "created": "2021-02-26 10:45:14",
        "status": "approved",
        "ref": "12452",
        "brand": "edr",
        "reason": "jkjkj"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://bvc/20",
        "created": "2021-02-26 10:43:18",
        "status": "rejected",
        "ref": "14562",
        "brand": "yghj",
        "reason": "asd",
    }
]
```

We have an class.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GetDetails {

    private List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<>();

// getters, setters and toString() 
    
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Detail {

    @JsonProperty(value = "url")
    private String url;

    @JsonProperty(value = "created")
    private Instant created;

    @JsonProperty(value = "status")
    private String status;

    @JsonProperty(value = "ref")
    private String ref;

    @JsonProperty(value = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @JsonProperty(value = "reason")
    private String reason;

//Getters, Setters and toString()

}
```

But while converting we are getting below error

> ERROR com.openbet.commons.sdk.common.util.RequestSenderImpl - Unexpected exception during HTTP exchange:
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.document.GetDetails` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.document.GetDetails` out of START_ARRAY token

Can someone suggest me what's wrong I've done here?

Comment: get "List<Details> list" as request body. You don't have details property in json

Comment: Then how do I create class. That class should hold list of Details

Comment: how are you converting json to object? You don't need to use GetDetails. You have used jackons annotations so you can convert it to List<Detail>

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getDetails(@RequestBody List<Detail> details){}
```

method signature example for your case.

There is not details property in json

You are trying to convert example below so you can not convert it

```
{
  details : [
    {
        "url": "https://abc/10",
        "created": "2021-02-26 10:45:14",
        "status": "approved",
        "ref": "12452",
        "brand": "edr",
        "reason": "jkjkj"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://bvc/20",
        "created": "2021-02-26 10:43:18",
        "status": "rejected",
        "ref": "14562",
        "brand": "yghj",
        "reason": "asd",
    }
  ]
}
```